# grpc protobuf error cannot find module in nestjs

Tags: typescript, nestjs, protocol-buffers, grpc, protoc

I have generated ts protobuf via protoc command

```
protoc --plugin=\"protoc-gen-ts=.\\node_modules\\.bin\\protoc-gen-ts.cmd\" --plugin=\"protoc-gen-grpc=.\\node_modules\\.bin\\grpc_tools_node_protoc_plugin.cmd\" --js_out=\"import_style=commonjs,binary:./src/protos/interfaces\" --ts_out=\"service=grpc-node,mode=grpc-js:./src/protos/interfaces\" --grpc_out=\"./src/protos/interfaces\" ./src/protos/*.proto
```

It generated one **login_pb.js** and **login_pb.d.ts**

When I import it on nestjs app getting the below error and path of import is very correct.

import * as LoginPB from '../protos/interfaces/src/protos/login_pb';

**Below is the error :**
Error: Cannot find module '../protos/interfaces/src/protos/login_pb'